# Proof by cases. Formulate a conjecture. I don't get it. Question inside.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I don't understand this math question for my discrete math 2 class.

FOrmulate a conjecture about the decimal digits that appear as the final decimal digit of the fourth power of an integer. Prove your conjecture using a proof by cases.

So that is the question. I'm having trouble figuring out the answer. ANy insight appreciated.

Comment: The question asks you to come up with a conjecture. I'd try taking the 4th powers of the integers 1 through 10 and see if you notice any pattern in the final digit.

Comment: Try calculating $n^4$ mod $10$, for $0 \leq n \leq 9$.

Comment: Well, that is the boring part, so here are a few 1,16,81,256,625,1296,2401,4096,6561,10000,14641,20736,28561. Now think what happens to the last digit of $n^4$ if you increase $n$ by some suitable number.

Comment: It's not the boring part, it's the whole point. If we write $[n]$ to denote the residue of $n$ mod $10$, then $[n^4] = [n]^4$, so it suffices to consider $0 \leq n \leq 9$. You won't get any new final digits by considering larger values of $n$.

Comment: Everyone's saying the same thing in different ways. (That's a good thing, by the way.)

Comment: A better question title: "Formulate a conjecture about the final decimal digit of the fourth power of an integer."

Comment: Yet another way of stating the hint: let $n$ be any integer. How many of the digits of $n$ (and which ones) would you have to know in order to know what the last digit of $n^4$ is?

Answer (score 2):

try this :-

first see what is **$n^4$** for first integers **$n$**

$ 0^4 ={\color{Red} 0}\\ 1^4 ={\color{Red} 1}\\
2^4=1{\color{Red} 6}\\
3^4=8{\color{Red} 1}\\
4^4=25{\color{Red} 6}\\
5^4=62{\color{Red} 5}\\
6^4=129{\color{Red} 6}\\
7^4=240{\color{Red} 1}\\
8^4=409{\color{Red} 6}\\
9^4=656{\color{Red} 1}\\
10^4=1000{\color{Red} 0}\\
11^4=1464{\color{Red} 1}\\
12^4=2073{\color{Red} 6}\\ ...$

> **conjecture :** final decimal digit of the fourth power of an
>   integer would be (0,1,6,5)

**Proof :-**
let $n_i$ be any integer number s.t $i$ is number of digits then
$n_i=a_{i-1} 10^{i-1}+a_{i-2}10^{i-2}+...+a_110^1+a_010^0$  ,s.t $a_j$ is unit digit

then
$n_i \bmod 10=a_{i-1} 10^{i-1}+a_{i-2}10^{i-2}+...+a_110^1+a_010^0 \bmod 10= {\color{Red} {a_0}} \bmod 10$
thus :-
$n_i^4\bmod 10 ={\color{Red} {a_0^4}} \bmod 10 $

but $ 0\le a_0 \le 9 $ so we would have 10 cases for $n_i^4\bmod 10$

**by cases :-**

$ n_i^4\bmod 10 = 0^4 \mod10 ={\color{Red} 0}\mod 10\\n_i^4\bmod 10 =1^4 \mod 10 ={\color{Red} 1}\mod 10\\
n_i^4\bmod 10 =2^4 \bmod 10= {\color{Red} 6}\bmod 10\\
n_i^4\bmod 10 =3^4\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 1}\bmod 10\\
n_i^4\bmod 10 =4^4\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 6}\bmod 10\\
n_i^4\bmod 10 =5^4\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 5}\bmod 10\\
n_i^4\bmod 10 =6^4\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 6}\bmod 10\\
n_i^4\bmod 10 =7^4\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 1}\bmod 10\\
n_i^4\bmod 10 =8^4\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 6}\bmod 10\\
n_i^4\bmod 10 =9^4\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 1}\bmod 10\\$

**other method to prove  it ,  $n_i^4=(n_i^2)^2$ and last digit of a square $\in  \left \{  0,1,4,9,5,6   \right \} $  so you would have 6 cases to check**

$n_i^2\bmod 10 =0^2 \bmod 10= {\color{Red} 0}\bmod 10\\
n_i^2\bmod 10 =1^2\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 1}\bmod 10\\
n_i^2\bmod 10 =4^2\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 6}\bmod 10\\
n_i^2\bmod 10 =5^2\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 5}\bmod 10\\
n_i^2\bmod 10 =6^2\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 6}\bmod 10\\
n_i^2\bmod 10 =9^2\bmod 10= {\color{Red} 1}\bmod 10\\$

Comment: So using the proof by cases I would list the values of n? This may sound stupid but what does mod mean? I am getting a masters in CS and I havent taken discrete math 1 in like 5 years!

Comment: proof by cases means list of possible values of the remainder when n divided 10 not for n itself . , mod means "modulo" which is the remainder from  division operation [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation], now if you have integer n then n mod 10 gives the remainder when we divide by 10 , which give the first digit right ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to prove it.

Let's formulate a conjecture.

> $
> (-3)^4 = 8 \\
> (-2)^4 = 16 \\
> (-1)^4 = 1\\
> 0^4    = 0\\
> 1^4    = 1\\
> 2^4    = 16\\
> 3^4    = 81\\
> 4^4    = 256\\
> 5^4    = 625\\
> 6^4    = 1296\\
> 7^4    = 2401\\
> $

> Conjecture: The final decimal digit of the fourth power of an integer is either 0,1,5 or 6.

**Proof**: We use proof by cases. Assume n is an integer.  Then n=10a+b, where a and b are positive integers and b, is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9. Taking fourth power on both sides gives us:
$
\hspace{1cm}  n^4 = (10a + b)^4 \\
\hspace{1cm}  n^4 = 10000a^4 + 4000a^3b + 600a^2b^2 +40ab^3 + b^4 \\
\hspace{1cm}  n^4 = 10(1000a^4 + 400a^3b + 60a^2b^2 +4ab^3) + b^4\\
\text{thus, } n^4 = 10k + b^4 \text{ where } k = 1000a^4 + 400a^3b + 60a^2b^2 +4ab^3.$

Notice that the last digit of $n^4$ is the same as the last digit of $b^4$. At this point, we can check the last digit of all possible $n^4$ by checking only the last digit of all $b^4$, and we can do that by exhaustion since our b only has 10 integers as declared earlier. We have reduced it to just 10 cases, but we can do better.

since $(10-b)^4 = 10(1000 + 400b + 60b^2 + 4b^3) + b^4$, the last digit of $b^4$ is the same as the last digit of $(10-b)^4$. This tells us that the final digit of 1 and 9, 2 and 8, 3 and 7, 4 and 6 to the fourth power are the same. This reduces our cases to just 6:

**case1:** When the last digit of n is 1 or 9, then the final digit of $n^4$ is the same as the final digit of $1^4 = 1$ or $9^4 = 6561$
which is 1.

**case2:** When the last digit of n is 2 or 8, then the final digit of $n^4$ is the same as the final digit of $2^4 = 16$ or $8^4 = 4096$
which is 6.

**case3:** When the last digit of n is 3 or 7, then the final digit of $n^4$ is the same as the final digit of $3^4 = 81$ or $7^4 = 2401$
which is 1.

**case4:** When the last digit of n is 4 or 6, then the final digit of $n^4$ is the same as the final digit of $4^4 = 256$ or $6^4 = 1296$ which is 6.

**case5:** When the last digit of n is 5, then the final digit of $n^4$ is the same as the final digit of $5^4 = 625$ which is 5.

**case6:** When the last digit of n is 0, then the final digit of $n^4$ is the same as the final digit of $0^4 = 0$ which is 0.

∴In all cases, the final digit of the fourth power of an integer is either 0,1,5 or 6 as desired. □